# Python function repeating output based on list contents

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have a python function that lists servers in AWS EC2.

For some reason it's repeating the same server info (same instance ID, ip addresses etc) for each region that it loops through. Problem is each region should be unique and have it's own servers with different info.

If I have one region in this list the servers are listed once:

```
regions = ['us-east-1']
```

If I have two regions in the list the same info repeats twice:

```
regions = ['us-east-1', 'us-east-2']
```

If I have three regions the same info repeats 3 times, and so on...

This is my function:

```
def list_instances(aws_account,aws_account_number, interactive, regions, fieldnames, show_details):
    today, aws_env_list, output_file, output_file_name, fieldnames = initialize(interactive, aws_account)
    options = arguments()
    instance_list = ''
    session = ''
    ec2 = ''
    account_found = ''
    PrivateDNS = None
    block_device_list = None
    instance_count = 0
    account_type_message = ''
    profile_missing_message = ''
    region = ''
    # Set the ec2 dictionary
    ec2info = {}
    # Write the file headers
    if interactive == 1:
        with open(output_file, mode='w+') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
            writer.writeheader()
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account,region_name=region)
    print(Fore.CYAN)      
    report_gov_or_comm(aws_account, account_found)
    print(Fore.RESET)
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account)
    account_found = 'yes'
    ec2 = session.client("ec2")
    for i in range(len(regions)):
        session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account, region_name=region[i])
        print(f"*****Region: {region}*******")
        # Loop through the instances
        try:
            instance_list = ec2.describe_instances()
        except Exception as e:
                pass
        try:
            for reservation in instance_list["Reservations"]:
                for instance in reservation.get("Instances", []):
                    instance_count = instance_count + 1
                    launch_time = instance["LaunchTime"]
                    launch_time_friendly = launch_time.strftime("%B %d %Y")
                    tree = objectpath.Tree(instance)
                    block_devices = set(tree.execute('$..BlockDeviceMappings[\'Ebs\'][\'VolumeId\']'))
                    if block_devices:
                        block_devices = list(block_devices)
                        block_devices = str(block_devices).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\'','')
                    else:
                        block_devices = None
                    private_ips =  set(tree.execute('$..PrivateIpAddress'))
                    if private_ips:
                        private_ips_list = list(private_ips)
                        private_ips_list = str(private_ips_list).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\'','')
                    else:
                        private_ips_list = None
                    type(private_ips_list)
                    public_ips =  set(tree.execute('$..PublicIp'))
                    if len(public_ips) == 0:
                        public_ips = None
                    if public_ips:
                        public_ips_list = list(public_ips)
                        public_ips_list = str(public_ips_list).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\'','')
                    else:
                        public_ips_list = None
                    if 'KeyName' in instance:
                        key_name = instance['KeyName']
                    else:
                        key_name = None
                    name = None
                    if 'Tags' in instance:
                        try:
                            tags = instance['Tags']
                            name = None
                            for tag in tags:
                                if tag["Key"] == "Name":
                                    name = tag["Value"]
                                if tag["Key"] == "Engagement" or tag["Key"] == "Engagement Code":
                                    engagement = tag["Value"]
                        except ValueError:
                            # print("Instance: %s has no tags" % instance_id)
                            pass
                    if 'VpcId' in instance:
                        vpc_id = instance['VpcId']
                    else:
                        vpc_id = None
                    if 'PrivateDnsName' in instance:
                        private_dns = instance['PrivateDnsName']
                    else:
                        private_dns = None
                    ec2info[instance['InstanceId']] = {
                        'AWS Account': aws_account,
                        'Account Number': aws_account_number,
                        'Name': name,
                        'Instance ID': instance['InstanceId'],
                        'Volumes': block_devices,
                        'Private IP': private_ips_list,
                        'Public IP': public_ips_list,
                        'Private DNS': private_dns,
                        'Availability Zone': instance['Placement']['AvailabilityZone'],
                        'VPC ID': vpc_id,
                        'Type': instance['InstanceType'],
                        'Key Pair Name': key_name,
                        'State': instance['State']['Name'],
                        'Launch Date': launch_time_friendly
                    }
                    with open(output_file,'a') as csv_file:
                        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
                        writer.writerow({'AWS Account': aws_account, "Account Number": aws_account_number, 'Name': name, 'Instance ID': instance["InstanceId"], 'Volumes': block_devices,  'Private IP': private_ips_list, 'Public IP': public_ips_list, 'Private DNS': private_dns, 'Availability Zone': instance['Placement']['AvailabilityZone'], 'VPC ID': vpc_id, 'Type': instance["InstanceType"], 'Key Pair Name': key_name, 'State': instance["State"]["Name"], 'Launch Date': launch_time_friendly})
                    ec2_info_items = ec2info.items
                    if show_details == 'y' or show_details == 'yes':
                        for instance_id, instance in ec2_info_items():
                            if account_found == 'yes':
                                print(Fore.RESET + "-------------------------------------")
                                for key in [
                                    'AWS Account',
                                    'Account Number',
                                    'Name',
                                    'Instance ID',
                                    'Volumes',
                                    'Private IP',
                                    'Public IP',
                                    'Private DNS',
                                    'Availability Zone',
                                    'VPC ID',
                                    'Type',
                                    'Key Pair Name',
                                    'State',
                                    'Launch Date'
                                ]:
                                    print(Fore.GREEN + f"{key}: {instance.get(key)}")
                                print(Fore.RESET + "-------------------------------------")
                        else:
                            pass
                    reservation = {}
                    instance = {}
                    ec2_info_items = {}
                    ec2info = {}
                    with open(output_file,'a') as csv_file:
                        csv_file.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An exception has occurred: {e}")
    if profile_missing_message == '*':
        banner(profile_missing_message)
    print(Fore.GREEN)
    report_instance_stats(instance_count, aws_account, account_found)
    print(Fore.RESET + '\n')
    #breakpoint()
    return output_file

def main():
    aws_account = 'us-account-1'
    aws_account_number = '123456789101'
    regions = ['us-east-1', 'us-east-2']
    show_details = 'yes'
    output_file = list_instances(aws_account,aws_account_number, interactive, regions, fieldnames, show_details)

if __name__ == __main__:
    main()
```

I've tried resetting some values at the end of the function to get it to stop repeating the same info over and over again based on the contents of the `regions` list. But that didn't work!

```
        reservation = {}
        instance = {}
        ec2_info_items = {}
        ec2info = {}
```

Why is the same info repeating over and over again based on the contents of the `regions` list?

Comment: Where are you actually telling the system which region you are looking at?  Simply looping over the regions isn't going to do it.

Comment: Did you try to move `session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account,region_name=region)` inside the loop?

Comment: You don't show how you _call_ `list_instances()`. That's probably where the error is.

Comment: I'm only calling `list_instances()` once. Should've mentioned that in the OP.

Comment: it cannot be called without arguments

Comment: yep. I've included the line to show how I'm calling `list_instances()` in the OP.

Comment: The code as presented should raise a `NameError` at `region_name=region` because at that point in the code you have not defined a name `region`, have you?

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the OP to the actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've created your EC2 client object once, for the default region, and you never update it for the other regions.

Change this:

```
ec2 = session.client("ec2")
for i in range(len(regions)):
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account, region_name=region[i])
    print(f"*****Region: {region}*******")
    # Loop through the instances
    try:
        instance_list = ec2.describe_instances()
```

to this:

```
for region in regions:
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account, region_name=region)
    ec2 = session.client("ec2")
    print(f"*****Region: {region}*******")
    # Loop through the instances
    try:
        instance_list = ec2.describe_instances()
```